# Why do my recusion functions even work? Syntax confusing

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have written two recursive functions, which work almost identically. I was trying to get the recursion right and then I accidentally stumbled upon the answer, but the syntax confuses me:

```py
def fac(N):

    """
    Factorial of N.
    """
    ################# This makes no goddamn sense to me #################
    if N == 1:
        return N
    ####### because N == 1, yet 'return N' is the correct result ########
    elif N == 0:
        return 1

    return N*fac(N-1)
```

How can N == 1 be true as the exit condition but also store the result of fac(N)? Same thing with a function `prod()`, which is the analog to `sum()`.

```py
def prod(List):

    """
    Product of all numbers in a list.
    """

    if len(List) == 1:
        return List[-1]

    return List[-1]*prod(List[:-1])
```

I don't get how the end result is stored in `List[-1]`. Does the python interpreter understand `return arg*func(arg)` in a special way?

Comment: There's no magic storing factorials in `N`. It just happens that when `N` is `1`, the correct factorial is also `1`. You could have had `return 1` there.

Comment: This is not a Python question but rather a question on how recursion works. Please read about recursion and call stack. | But basically: if you execute any function, program remembers where it was before it, with each finished `return`, it gets back to that remembered place. In case of recursion, it's a whole stack of calls. Only when the innermost call hits the `if`, its return doesn't call anything so it really returns. Then its outer one returns, then the next one... and then you finally get back. **Outermost result is your real result.**

Comment: So the function constructs a function that basically says ```func(func(func(N))))``` and when it hits a ```return 1``` it evaluates all of it?

Comment: J.Doe -- not nested calls but IN THEORY it's building a `(N-3) * (N-2) * (N-1) * func(N)` chain and when finally `N` is either 0 or 1 the chain is complete and the result is "evaluated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the loops required to calculate `fac(4)`:

```
1: fac(4) -> 4 * fac(3)  # It then has to calculate fac(3)
2: fac(3) -> 3 * fac(2)  # It then has to calculate fac(2)
3: fac(2) -> 2 * fac(1)  # It then has to calculate fac(1)

4: fac(1) -> 1  # Finally we've returned a value - now back up through the loops

3: fac(2) -> 2 * fac(1) == 2 * 1 == 2
2: fac(3) -> 3 * fac(2) == 3 * 2 == 6
1: fac(4) -> 4 * fac(3) == 4 * 6 == 24
```

The second part is effectively the same thing - recurse down until you get a value, then keep plugging that in all the way back up to your original request.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special, but in case like this, use print and explore.

```py
def fac(N): 
""" Factorial of N. """  
    if N == 1: 
        return N
    elif N == 0: 
        return 1 
     return N*fac(N-1)
```

Let see how it's work for fac(3)

```py
# fac(3)
# fac(3) => 3 * fac(3-1)
# fac(3) => 3 * fac(3-1) => 2 * fac(2-1)
# fac(3) => 3 * fac(3-1) => 2 * fac(2-1) => return 1
# fac(3) => 3 * fac(3-1)  <= 2 * 1
# fac(3) <=  3 * 2 * 1
# 6
```